# Asynchronously load a view in asp.net core MVC

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm on a ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller) on .NET 6.0 and I'm trying to show a determinate view when some internal asynchronous task wants.

Here's what I've tried:

```
Task.RunAsync(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/Index");
    });
```

What it happens is that I get `System.ObjectDisposedException: IFeatureCollection has been disposed.`.

I've tried some other things like using IServiceScopeFactory but I don't completely know how to use it correctly.

I'd really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: You shouldn't use blocking operations like `Thread.Sleep` or directly accessing `HttpContext` within asynchronous tasks. This can lead to issues like the one you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid accessing `HttpContext` directly within the `Task.RunAsync` method. You can use `IServiceScopeFactory`.

Example:

```
private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

public YourController(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
{
    _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
}
```

In your action method:

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var urlHelper = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUrlHelper>();
        var url = urlHelper.Action("Index", "Home");
        Response.Redirect(url);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this did not work, i got the following error: `InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IUrlHelper' has been registered.` on the `var urlHelper = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUrlHelper>();` line. Do I miss something like ading a `builder.service()` ?

Comment: You need to register the `IUrlHelper` service in your application's dependency injection container. 
`builder.Services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUrlHelper>(provider =>
{
    var actionContext = provider.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext;
    var factory = provider.GetRequiredService<IUrlHelperFactory>();
    return factory.GetUrlHelper(actionContext);
});`

Answer (score 3):

You can't redirect your user after a page is loaded by using `HttpContext.Current.Response` as this uses HTTP redirect codes (which you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirect?view=netframework-4.8.1&viewFallbackFrom=net-7.0)). If your user see's a page (which I assume after 10 seconds is the case) you already have returned a `200` code. And after that you can't return a other one, as the request is already fulfilled. You can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) how HTTP redirection works if you want to.

If you want to implement redirection after a page load, you will need to implement some JavaScript which does the redirection for you. This can be achieved for example by doing:

```js
window.location.href = "/yourNewUrl";
```

But you will want to call this JS only after something in your backend is completed so you may want to add an API endpoint which you can call and returns after your operation is completed:

```js
fetch("https://path/to/your/endpoint").then(x => window.location.href = "/yourNewUrl")
```

Note: that `fetch` will timeout after 300 seconds in chrome and after 90 seconds in Firefox. If your operations take much longer or you want to redirect your user regularly you may want to use a WebSocket instead.

If you know exactly how long the delay will be you don't need JS you can simply use an meta refresh tag in your header which will force the browser to automatically redirect your user to the given URL after the time specified in `content`:

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; URL=http://www.example.com/">
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it seems like what I was asking for. However I've come up with SignalR and I'm trying to use it because I only want to show real time info.